# DrawerLayout above Linear Layout

Tags: android

I have just added a DrawerLayout to my activity.xml.  Running into spacing issues...I need the drawer layout to sit right above my main linear layout.  Right now getting an error that says: "Multiple root tags".

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.my.app.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Getting multiple root tags error below:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_lst_car"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_empty_list_cars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/view1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_cars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_header"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_header"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: post logcat of the error

Comment: post the entire layout.xml in one go, don't split it up.

Comment: What I posted is the entire layout.xml

Comment: @4k3R I think the second layout shown is @layout/toolbar included in the first one. neo just hasn't labeled it clearly for us.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the second LinearLayout.. thats your problem... I hope the Listening can help you:)

```
<!-- First Child represents the Activity layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onButtonClickMain"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

An XML document can only have **1** root element, in your second XML file you forget to close the main tag so this is why you have `Multiple root tags` error.

Just add `</LinearLayout>` at the end of the file to close your main `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wrapping the whole thing around RelativeLayout.